# Using pipes and structures with dynamically allocated variables in C

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, fork

I'm writting a program that needs to pass a matrix from a parent process to its child (that's why I'm using the `fork()` instruction). I've just read [this](http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html) and [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/136977-passing-struct-2-dynamic-arrays-through-pipe-reading-'s-data.html) to solve the problem myself, but I still can't understand how to use the `read()` and `write()` instructions with the pipe I've created so far. I know these instructions write series of bytes, but I'm not sure about using them with structures or dynamically allocated variables (like a matrix).

Here is the code I used to test (note the comments I put):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// Structure definition (Matrix)
typedef struct {
    int **mat;
    int rows;
    int cols;
} Matrix;

int main() {
    // Create the pipe
    int file_desc[2];
    if (pipe(file_desc) != 0) exit(1);

    // Create two processes
    if (fork() == 0) {
        /** Instructions for the child process */
        // Read the matrix structure from the pipe
        Matrix *received = NULL;
        read(file_desc[0], received, sizeof *received);
        if (received != NULL) {
            // Print the received matrix
            int i, j;
            printf("The matrix I've just *received* from the parent is:\n");
            for (i = 0; i < received->cols; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < received->rows; j++) printf("%d\t", received->mat[i][j]);
                printf("\n");
            }
        } else printf("received = NULL :'(\n");
    } else {
        /** Instructions for the parent process */
        /* Create a matrix dinamically.
         * In fact, in the real program I have a function to create a matrix given the
         * rows and columns, and fill it with random values, so it returns a Matrix *
         * (pointer to Matrix), but for testing purposes I've only written this
         * (also useful if I need an array of Matrix elements, for example)
         * */
        Matrix *myMatrix = calloc(1, sizeof *myMatrix);

        // Put the contents into the variable
        myMatrix->rows = 2;
        myMatrix->cols = 2;
        myMatrix->mat = calloc(myMatrix->rows, sizeof *(myMatrix->mat));
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < myMatrix->cols; i++)
            (myMatrix->mat)[i] = calloc(myMatrix->cols, sizeof **(myMatrix->mat));

        // Fill the matrix with some values (testing)
        (myMatrix->mat)[0][0] = 4;
        (myMatrix->mat)[0][1] = 2;
        (myMatrix->mat)[1][0] = 1;
        (myMatrix->mat)[1][1] = 3;

        // Print the matrix
        printf("The matrix I've just filled in the parent is:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < myMatrix->cols; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < myMatrix->rows; j++) printf("%d\t", myMatrix->mat[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        // Write the matrix structure to the pipe (here is where I have the problem!)
        write(file_desc[1], myMatrix, sizeof *myMatrix);

        // Wait for the child process to terminate
        wait(0);
        printf("The child process has just finished, the parent process continues.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, I tried first with a pointer to an `int` and it worked. But when I run this program, I receive this output:

```
The matrix I've just filled in the parent is:
4   2   
1   3   
received = NULL :'(
The child process has just finished, the parent process continues.
```

And I don't know why I get the NULL -- I'm almost sure I'm using the `write()` instruction incorrectly. Any help about this will be appreciated =)

**EDIT:** I think the matrix should be converted to text, for example, and then pass the string to the child, parse it and convert it to a Matrix structure again. I don't know if this approach is the best. Is there another approach besides this one?

**EDIT:** I tried the same code with a static variable (changing `int **mat;` to `int mat[2][2];` inside the structure declaration) but the user should change the matrix size.

Comment: I think you need to synchronize the child and parent process. It might be the case when child process is firstly created and read the data before parent writes into it. Also check the return value of read operation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a serious problem:

```
Matrix *received = NULL;
read(file_desc[0], received, sizeof *received);
```

Received is a null pointer.  That `read` is going to try to write data to NULL, which is an invalid address.  It would be much simpler to write:

```
Matrix received;
read(file_desc[0], &received, sizeof received);
```

Comment: I've just done this, the child process can't still receive the matrix from the parent. I think there are other errors in the code.

Comment: Allocating memory in the parent and then passing the address of the memory to the child is doomed to fail!

Comment: I see. So is it better to use static variables in cases like this?

Comment: No, static variable are irrelevant.  But you need to actually pass the data through the pipe, not just addresses.  Try using arrays instead of pointers in the struct.  You can use a variable length array if necessary, but that will make it harder to read since you'll need a protocol defined for passing the length through.  Get it working first with `struct {int mat[2][2];}`

Comment: In fact, I meant with "static variable" the same thing you wrote. Using your advice, it works (in fact, I tried that before asking). Unfortunately, I need a dynamically allocated variable because the user can change the matrix size.

Comment: How about using other shared memory mechanism like mmap? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html